# Mathematical equation using { with following three lines

Tags: math-mode, math-operators

I would like to typeset the following equation in LaTeX:

[image]

However, I am stuck here:

```
\begin{equation} \label{OBV1}
    \begin{split}
        OBV = OBV\textsubscript{previous} + \Bigg\{
    \end{split}
\end{equation}
```

which yields:

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is another solution, with `cases` and a simple `tabular`:

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\begin{document}

    \begin{equation} \label{OBV1}
    OBV = OBV\textsubscript{previous} + \begin{cases}
\begin{tabular}{@{}cl@{}}
   volume & if\, close $ > $ close\textsubscript{previous} \\
    0 & if\, close $ = $ close\textsubscript{previous} \\
    $-$volume & if \,close $ < $ close\textsubscript{previous}
\end{tabular}
    \end{cases}
    \end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I thought using `array` was simpler.

Comment: Not here, because almost everything after the brace has to be in text mode, which is ensured by `tabular`.

Comment: Huhh, I see! good one though :)

Answer (score 3):

I hope this helps you:

please use `\begin{cases}...\end{cases}` to get your desired results.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\begin{document}
    \begin{equation} \label{OBV1}
    \begin{split}
    OBV = OBV\textsubscript{previous} + \begin{cases}
    a,&\text{if}\\
    b,&\text{if}\\
    c,&\text{if}
    \end{cases}
    \end{split}
    \end{equation}
\end{document}
```

which would give you

[image]

Just fill-in your content(s).

Also, as @egreg mentioned `mathtools` provided text output in the second column of cases with `cases*`.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{empheq}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
    \begin{equation} \label{OBV1}
    OBV = OBV\textsubscript{previous} + \begin{cases*}
    a,&if\\
    b,&if\\
    c,&{if}
    \end{cases*}
    \end{equation}
\end{document}
```

see:

[image]

As per the OP comments, to center the cases:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[overload]{empheq}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
\[
OBV=OBV\textsubscript{prev}+\left\{\begin{array}{cl}  % first column is centered
\text{volume} & \text{if} \\
0                                                 & \text{if}\\
\text{volume}&\text{if}
\end{array}
\right.
\]
\end{document}
```

which gives us

[image]

Comment: `if` should be in text mode

Comment: @RaajaG how would I centrally align the `volume`,`0`,`-volume` as well? They seem to be left justified...:(

Comment: Incidentally,  `mathtools` defines a `cases*` , for which the second column is in text mode.

Comment: @Bernard thanks for the info, updated the answer.

Comment: @3kstc please see the updated answer

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest the following improvements:

1. use the `cases*` construct from mathtools to get the right column in text-mode by default
2. use `\makebox[..]{..}` to center the left column
3. `OBV` doesn't mean `O*B*V` as LaTeX understands, but a variable name, so `\mathit{OBV}` is the correct usage
4. use `^{}_` before `\text{previous}` to lower the word a bit

Here is the code:

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}

\newcommand{\CB}[1]{\makebox[4em]{#1}}

\begin{equation} \label{OBV2}
  \mathit{OBV} = \mathit{OBV}_\text{previous} + \begin{cases*}
    \CB{volume}    & if close $ > $ close$^{}_\text{previous}$ \\
    \CB{0}         & if close $ = $ close$^{}_\text{previous}$ \\
    \CB{$-$volume} & if close $ < $ close$^{}_\text{previous}$
  \end{cases*}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]